# How to save signed in username with the form to database? Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

All other data is saved ideally but as shown below, the user id part shows as a pull down bar and a null value which should be a signed-in username.

What's wrong with my code?
[The database page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iV42.png)

Here's my code.

**views.py**

```
from .models import Markers
from .forms import AddMarkersInfo
from django.http import HttpResponse

def addinfo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mks = AddMarkersInfo(request.POST)
        if mks.is_valid():
            submit = mks.save(commit=False)
            submit.user = request.user
            submit.save()

            name = mks.cleaned_data['name']
            address = mks.cleaned_data['address']
            description = mks.cleaned_data['description']
            type = mks.cleaned_data['type']
            lat = mks.cleaned_data['lat']
            lng = mks.cleaned_data['lng']

            Markers.objects.get_or_create(name=name, address=address, description=description,  type=type, lat=lat, lng=lng)
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'mks': mks })
    else:
        mks = AddMarkersInfo()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'mks': mks})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def get_sentinel_user():
    return get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(username='deleted')[0]

class Markers(models.Model):
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    use_id= models.ForeignKey(User, null=True,  on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user),)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60,default = 'name')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100,default = 'address')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='description')
    types = (
        ('m', 'museum'),
        ('s', 'school'),
        ('r', 'restaurant'),
        ('o', 'other'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=types, default='museum')
    lat = models.IntegerField()
    lng = models.IntegerField()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from maps.models import Markers

class AddMarkersInfo(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Markers
        fields = ['name','address','description', 'type','lat','lng',]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, you should remove the lines `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and `User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `models.py` if you are going to use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. You should use only one of the two.

And you can change your field to:

```
use_id= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, ...
```

---

Secondly, it seems like you are duplicating the creation. The lines

```
submit = mks.save(commit=False)
submit.user = request.user
submit.save()
```

already create an `Markers` instance, so there is no need to call `Markers.objects.get_or_create(...` after that.

And, according to you models, the field should be `submit.use_id` instead of `submit.user`.

---

Now, if I understand your question correctly you want to make the `use_id` field read-only in your form/template.

I don't know why that field is even showing up in your form, since it is not listed in your forms `Meta.fields`.

You could try something like setting the widget attribute `readonly`:

```
class AddMarkersInfo(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Markers
        fields = ['use_id', 'name', 'address', 'description', 'type', 'lat', 'lng']
        widgets = {
            'use_id': forms.Textarea(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        }
```